# Which pin "is already in use"?

Tags: gpio, python

I'm getting a `RuntimeWarning: This channel is already in use, continuing anyway.` from a line of code that gets run many times with different pins. I'm concerned that I may be trying to use a GPIO pin that was already being used for something else (for example, I already found one where I was using an I2C pin for GPIO while also using I2C). How can I figure out which pin is causing the error without just manually checking each one?

I tried looking for something like `issetup()` or similar to check before I run setup, but nothing like that appears to exist.

Answer (score 2):

You could just ignore the warning.

Alternatively I thought the warning told you what to do if you don't want the warning printed.

Alternatively call the cleanup() method before exiting the script.

Alternatively see which GPIO are exported.

```
$ ls /sys/class/gpio
export  gpio23  gpiochip0  gpiochip100  unexport
```

This shows that GPIO23 is in use.

Comment: I edited the question to point out that I don't want to just ignore the warning- I think it may be pointing out a real problem. The check suggestion is useful though. For anyone else that wants to do it in-program, I figured out that `os.listdir('/sys/class/gpio')` works similarly.